# cannot import name 'StackingClassifier' from 'sklearn.ensemble'

Tags: machine-learning

I was trying to use stacking by using Scikit-learn, but it throws this import error,I tried other imports from ensenble like RandomForest etc. they work fine.

Answer (score 8):

Just run the following command in Anaconda or cmd ,because it was not there in the previous versions.

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: I used this code and sklearn version is 0.24.1 but I face the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Restarting the kernel and clearing output**  after running the command nofoobar posted seems to have resolved the issue for me.

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).